# dissipative operator meaning

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Can someone explain to me the "meaning" of the dissipative operator ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_operator

I am a bit confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I deleted my answer that this question get back the status of being unanswerded. Maybe so you will get a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we deal with some systems of PDEs (e.g., hyperbolic systems) via semigroup theory, we rewrite the system as an abstract Cauchy problem
$$\left\{\begin{align}&\frac{d}{dt}U=AU\\
&U(0)=U_0\end{align}\right.$$
where $A$ is an operator defined in a subspace of a suitable Hilbert space $(H,\|\cdot\|_H)$. In this abstract setting, the space $H$ is chosen so that the energy of the system satisfies
$$E(t)=\|U(t)\|_H^2=\langle U(t),U(t)\rangle_H.$$
As a consequence, 
$$\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=\left\langle \frac{d}{dt}U(t),U(t)\right\rangle_H+\left\langle U(t),\frac{d}{dt}U(t)\right\rangle_H=2\text{Re}\Big(\langle AU(t),U(t)\rangle_H\Big).$$
So, if $A$ is dissipative (that is, if it satisfies $\text{Re}(\langle Ax,x\rangle_H)\leq 0$ for all $x$) then the energy of the system has nonpositive derivative. Thus, in this context, **an operator be dissipative means that the energy of the system is nonincreasing**.

For other interpretations (and references on the interpretation above), I suggest that you take a look at the section 7 (pages 30-39) of the paper *[Recent developments in some non-self-adjoint problems of mathematical physics](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183523852)* by C. L. Dolph.