# Intuitions behind dissipative operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I Just started learning Hille Yosida theory. Im kinda stuck on dissipative operators, i dont get the intuition behind the notion of dissipative if there is any... Any help is welcome !

Comment: The origin of the term comes from a system with dissipation, such as the classical heat equation $\frac{dh}{dt} = Ah$ where $A=\nabla^2$. Dissipation occurs when the spectrum of $A$ is negative because $h(t)=e^{tA}h(0)$. The definition is adapted a little to given a condition that's appropriate for $C_0$ semigroups (especially contractive ones,) but the definition does not strictly imply invertibility for $A-\lambda I$ for $\lambda$ in the right half-plane because the bound $\|(A-\lambda I)x\|\ge \lambda\|x\|$ for $\lambda > 0$ does not imply that the range is full for such $\lambda$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1379692/70305).

Comment: In a sense we can say that a system of the form $U_t=AU$ (common in the context of the Hille-Yosida theorem) with $A$ *dissipative* is a system which *dissipates* energy. This interpretation is explained in the link above.